# how to use media queries with slide toggle menu with jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

a bit new to JS. i have a typical responsive menu with a **hamburger button**. it toggles correctly, but if i toggle to not show my menu and switch to a larger screen, the menu does not show even though my media query defaults to **display: block.**

it is the same for when i open the menu. if i leave the menu open at a smaller resolution, it will show my menu at larger screens. seems like my .expand class sticks no matter what the screen resolution is and doesn't default to my media query settings.

how do i fix this? here is my code, i use post css with mixins (scss and media queries), and ES6 class for JS (kind of unorthodox i guess but experimenting)

**CSS**

```
.primary-nav {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-10%);
          transform: translate(0,-10%);
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 340px) {
    .primary-nav .expand {
      display: block;
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 650px) {

.primary-nav {
    display: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-10%);
            transform: translate(0,-10%)
}

    .primary-nav .expand {
      display: block;
    }
  }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

.primary-nav {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 5vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 4rem
}
  }

@media (min-width: 1920px) {

.primary-nav {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    height: 7vh;
    display: block;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem
}
  }

.primary-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

.primary-nav ul {
      padding: 0
  }
  }

.primary-nav li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF00A2;
  }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

.primary-nav li {
      display: inline;
      padding-left: 2%;
      border-bottom: none
  }
  }

@media (min-width: 1920px) {

.primary-nav li {
      padding-left: 5%
  }
  }

.primary-nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

.primary-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(46, 198, 218);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
  }

@media (min-width: 650px) {

.primary-nav a {
      padding: 8px
  }
  }


 //postcss with mixins 
.primary-nav {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 1rem;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translate(0,-10%);
      display: none;

      .expand {
        display: block;
      }


      @mixin atMedium {
        display: none;
        font-size: 1rem;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(0,-10%);
      }

      @mixin atLarge {
        display: block;
        font-size: 1rem;
        height: 5vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 4rem;
      }

      @mixin atXLarge {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        height: 7vh;
        display: block;
        top: 1rem;
        left: 0;
        padding: 1rem;

      }

      ul {
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;


        @mixin atLarge {
          padding: 0;
        }
      }


      li {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $hotPink;

        @mixin atLarge {
          display: inline;
          padding-left: 2%;
          border-bottom: none;
        }

        @mixin atXLarge {
          padding-left: 5%;
        }
      }

      li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: $mainTeal;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px;

        @mixin atMedium {
          padding: 8px;
        }
      }
    }
```

**JS**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class MobileMenu {
  // dom selection usually and firing events when a page loads.
  constructor(){
    this.menuButton = $('.mobile-menu');
    this.events();
  }

  //events to watch for such as click
  events(){

    this.menuButton.on('click', function(){

        $('.primary-nav').slideToggle(400, function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('.expand');
          // console.log('hello');
        });

    });

  }

}

export default MobileMenu;
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="mobile-menu">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </span>

      <nav class="primary-nav col col--md-8 col--lg-8">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#hero">Project How To</a></li>
          <li><a href="#faq" >Rules/Terms</a></li>
          <li><a href="#blog" >Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#account">My Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#log" >Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="icons icons--cart fas fa-shopping-cart "></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

excuse the positioning, there is a logo i have near my nav menu which i have to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Can you please add compiled CSS as well?

Comment: i've added the compiled css. let me know if its still unclear. it was a large file so i tried picking out the same lines that i had orginally posted

Comment: Are you sure it's fully compiled? There `@mixins` still. One more thing could you please make your code into a [mcve]? You use the button with the brackets `<>`.